# C# Can't store design time values in designer Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

In my project I have a custom panel:

```
[Serializable]
public partial class ButtonPanel : UserControl
{
    private List<CompactButton> _compactButtons;

    public ButtonPanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _compactButtons = new List<CompactButton>();

        AddButtons();
    }

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content), Editor(typeof(ButtonPanelXEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    public List<CompactButton> CompactButtons
    {
        get { return _compactButtons; }
        set { _compactButtons = value; }
    }

    private void AddButtons()
    { 
        CompactButton c = new CompactButton();
        c.Enabled = baseButton1.Enabled;

        CompactButton c2 = new CompactButton();
        c2.Enabled = baseButton2.Enabled;

        _compactButtons.Add(c);
        _compactButtons.Add(c2);
    }
}
```

On a panel there are two buttons (baseButton1 and baseButton2). The state of these buttons must be saved in the designer. But because the `Button` class isn't serializable, I have created a custom class to store the most important properties, `CompactButton`:

```
[Serializable]
public class CompactButton
{
    #region Member variables
    private bool _visible;
    private bool _enabled;
    private string _tooltip;
    private string _name;
    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public CompactButton()
    { }
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }
    public bool Visible
    {
        get { return _visible; }
        set { _visible = value; }
    }
    public bool Enabled
    {
        get { return _enabled; }
        set { _enabled = value; }
    }
    public string ToolTipText
    {
        get { return _tooltip; }
        set { _tooltip = value; }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

As you can see in the `ButtonPanel` class, I have a property `CompactButtons` which returns a list with `CompactButtons`.

When I add my ButtonPanel in the designer and then build my application I get this error:

> ```
> Error 1   Could not find a type for a name.  The type name was
> ```
>
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[ButtonPanelX.CompactButton,
>   ButtonPanelX, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]], mscorlib,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. Line
>   131, position
>   5.    D:\Projecten\ButtonPanelX\ButtonPanelX\Form1.resx   131 5

What do I have to do to fix this?

Comment: +1: interesting problem. My first thought was, *CompactButtons isn't serializable*. However, you have that covered. My secondary thought is to maybe derive CompactButtons from `ISerializable`.

Comment: Thank you for commenting on me. I haven't try deriving from ISerializable. If I do this, do I have to implement all the methods? Or just use the default ones.

Comment: You must implement all the methods.

Comment: I'm also now wondering if you need to use another attribute. There is one that is suppose to make something **design-time visible**; I just don't recall the name of the attribute. You could also have CompactButtons derive from `Control`.

Comment: I can't derive from `Control` because it isn't serializable. Do you have other suggestions I can try? I have also tried to implement `ISerializable` but I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

I made a new project, pasted your example and it just works for me (after removing the references to stuff not included in the sample).

From your error message I suppose you changed something in the code and recompiled, now the RESX serialized format is no longer valid. Note that once you got serialized data you are very restricted in [what you can change](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms229752.aspx) in the class you serialized.

I'd suggest removing the controls from the designer file **and** resx file manually (open the resx with the xml editor) and place the control again.

One additional hint I have: You don't need to use [Serializable] on CompactButton at all. If you remove it VisualStudio will serialize by code into the designer.cs file instead of the resx file. I almost always prefer this because then I can manually edit the generated code when something changes.